# Chrome extension development on Ubuntu is like a pain

Tags: google-chrome, ubuntu, google-chrome-extension

I am developing my first extension for Chrome and as I am working on Ubuntu, I've encountered two awful bugs.

The first thing is that `chrome.i18n.getUILanguage` is not supported! (console gives me an error about unsupported method). The thing is that this problem is not listed on any WIKI page, which may become tricky for beginners. Anyone had similar issue? For now, I am using `window.navigator.language.`

The second bug is about rich notifications that are not supported (anyone knows when it will be released?). As far as I know, when the app will be about to send a notification, the scripts will stop due to the error (similar to the first bug). I am not sure if there is possibility to develop different packages for different platforms, but if I want my extension to be truly multi-platform, I will have to give up development of this feature.

Any suggestions or thoughts?

Thanks,

Comment: i'm also developing an extension with chrome and i've the same problem with chrome.i18n.getUILanguage... always reports undefined.

Answer (score 0):

As i said earlier in a comment, it seems to be not supported with linux mint either where i'm developing the chrome extension.

In this [link](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/apps-dev/aGRqsZDtDso) a member of the chrome team said that they submitted it... but this is not true.
Thanks for the `window.navigator.language` alternative.

Comment: Yup, I saw this discussion yesterday. I am not sure how the Chrome development process looks like, but maybe this feature has been already implemented in Windows and Mac only? Anyway, contacted dev-team, will update topic soon.